# Apex String Split with single quotes

Tags: apex, string

I have a String array as follows

```
String [] toAddress = new String [] {'abc@example.com','def@example.com','xyz@example.com'};
```

I would like to get the output as

```
'abc@example.com','def@example.com','xyz@example.com'.
```

Could you please give some direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean `String[] toAddress = new String[] { 'abc@example.com','def@example.com','xyz@example.com' };` ? The code isn't legal Apex Code as it stands.

Comment: @sfdcFox: You are right. I have update the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use String#join to get the output you want:

```
String result = '\''+String.join(toAddress,'\',\'')+'\'';
```

This will result in a single string with quoted addresses.

Comment: Thank you it worked. If I would like to learn more on the string methods do you suggest sites other MDN site?

Comment: @user28452 If you are working with strings in Apex, the best reference would be the [Apex Developers' Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)